# Webpack 4 - unable to load images with absolute path in src using url-loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4, urlloader

I have been been struggling with an issue with Webpack. I have tried searching everywhere online for a solution but did not manage to solve my problem.

I am building a React application with the following project structure:

```
package.json
webpack.config.js
src
- images
- components
-- Display
--- Display.js
--- config.js
- Frame
-- Frame.js
index.js
index.html
```

Here is `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require("path");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "index.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js)$/, use: "babel-loader" },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "url-loader",
          options: {
            name: "[name].[ext]"
          }
        }
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] },
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader" }
    ]
  },
  mode: "development",
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "src/index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

`config.js` provides a variable with the image path to `Display.js`, which then passes it to `Frame.js` as a prop. `Frame.js` renders the image with the provided path.

```
//config.js
export const imgPath = "/src/images/icon.gif";

//Display.js
import {imgPath} from "./config.js";
<Frame imgSrc={imgPath} />

//Frame.js
<img src={this.props.imgSrc} />
```

The problem I am facing is that the image `icon.gif` is not put in-line in the javascript bundle but instead the browser makes a request to fetch the file, which is not the expected behaviour. When I build the application in production mode, the image is not displayed at all.

Could someone please help me get this right? Basically, there are two problems I am facing:

1. The images are not made inline by the url-loader
2. The images are not displayed at all in production build.

Thank you!

Comment: Change `url-loader` loader to `file-loader`

Comment: I want to use `url-loader` in specific to reduce the number of requests. However, I had tried using `file-loader` but getting the same problem.

Comment: what is the type of imagePath in config.js?

Comment: It's a string. I had made an error in the code, but it's fixed now.

Comment: @Jspake Do you mean the problem is fixed now?

Comment: No, I meant the type of `imagePath` in `config.js` was wrong in the question only, but my actual code is correct. The problem still persists :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import the file first. But since your `publicPath` is set to '/', and your images are emitted into `dist`, the actual path to the image you need to use is `/icon.gif`.

1) Import all the possible files (Be sure to use the correct path here)

```
// includes.js

import './src/images/icon1.gif';
import './src/images/icon2.gif';
import './src/images/icon3.gif';
```

2) Export the production file path function

```
//config.js

import './includes.js';

export const imgPathFunc = num => `/icon${num}.gif`;
```

3) Import it in Display.js

```
//Display.js

import { imgPath } from "./config.js";

{serverResponse && <Frame imgSrc={imgPath(serverResponse)} />}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For part (1) do I need to import that in `config.js`? Also, I did try using the approach of importing images. However, this isn't a neat solution for my case because I am generating the path dynamically in `config.js`. Something like, `export const imgPath="/icon"+{some variable}+".gif"`, and there are many many images like these. Sorry, I should've stated that in my question.  
Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: @Jspake Yes you will need to import them first. Do you know the names and paths of all the images you want to import?

Comment: Yes, I do know the path names. But the images to be rendered keep changing depending on the data that I receive from the server. This is the problem.

Comment: @Jspake Well, in that case, you have to make sure any image path you get from the server is already included as part of the build.

Comment: I mean, the server only gives me a variable needed to form the image path. I do not actually get the entire path from the server

Comment: @Jspake Can you give an example of a network response, and an image path please?

Comment: So from the network response, I get a number between 1 and 9 in a variable, let's call this `serverResponse`. Then in config.js, I export the path as, `export const imgPath = "/src/images/icon"+serverResponse+".gif"`;

Comment: @Jspake Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, @Sreeram. Quick question: where exactly should I import all the possible files (from part 1)?

Comment: @Jspake It will be good to import put it in a separate file and import this file into config.js.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196052/discussion-between-jspake-and-sreeram).